# Attempting to delete registry keys with subkeys results in an error

Tags: c#, .net, registry

When I try to delete a key in HKCU that has subkeys I get an error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
using (RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\", true))
{
   if (regkey.OpenSubKey("Google") != null)
   {
      regkey.DeleteSubKey("Google");
   }
}
```

The error I get:

> Registry key has subkeys and recursive removes are not supported by this method.

How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `RegistryKey.DeleteSubKeyTree` method.

> [**RegistryKey.DeleteSubKeyTree Method (String)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3yfwzfx.aspx)
>
> Deletes a subkey and any child subkeys recursively.

```
using(RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\", true))
{
    if (regkey.OpenSubKey("Google") != null)
    {
        regkey.DeleteSubKeyTree("Google");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\", true))
{
   regkey?.DeleteSubKeyTree("Google");
}
```